# SOAP unable to parse returnvalue due to internal error MessageCreationException

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss7.x

I am connecting to a web service that gives me a com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException with a reference to "Internal Error. Didn't get Headers even after complete parsing."
The code in question has run fine for years until it suddenly throws the exception.
From server side, it seems everything is working fine: The message I send is transferred to the service, the service returns an object.

We have narrowed it down to the parsing of the returnvalue, over which I have no control.
We suspect jar-hell, and I have tried to manipulate the installation to get back to a point where I knew it worked, but to no avail.
From SOAP UI, everything works as expected.
My client is running on JBOSS 7 AS and I have tried JBOSS WildFly.

The stack trace points to decoding, MIMEPART. I would like to know how to resolve this issue.

```
com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal Error. Didn't get Headers even after complete parsing.
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:292)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:189)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
at !my call goes here
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.jsp.ajax.execmethod_jsp._jspService(execmethod_jsp.java:169)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal Error. Didn't get Headers even after complete parsing.
at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEPart.getHeaders(MIMEPart.java:144)
at org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEPart.getContentType(MIMEPart.java:134)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MimeMultipartParser$PartAttachment.getContentType(MimeMultipartParser.java:167)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:340)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.MimeCodec.decode(MimeCodec.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:279)
```